# Import CSV Using Laravel Excel (Maat)

Tags: laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

Hi I have an excel file with the details of passengers under the trip ID. I want to import that excel file in my table. please see the picture below:
[image]

the first row with the blue color is my column names on my table. my problem is how can I save the value of D2:G2 in `next_of_kin` table with this kind of format.

```
[
 {"name":James Lara,"mobile":12345678},
 {"name":Jasmine Lara,"mobile":12345678}
]
```

[image]

this is my code on my controller.

```
// Get excel file
$path = $request->file;

// Save the content to passenger
Excel::load($path, function ($reader) use ($request) {

 $trip = Trip::where('id', $request->trip_customer_id)->first();

 foreach ($reader->toArray() as $row) {
   $trip->passengers()->create($row);
 }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

on my foreach inside the controller this looks like.

```
foreach ($reader->toArray() as $row) {

   $given_name = array(
       ['name' =>$row['nok_one'],'mobile' => $row['nok_one_mobile']],
       ['name' =>$row['nok_two'],'mobile' => $row['nok_two_mobile']]
   );

   $trip->passengers()->create([
       'first_name' => $row['first_name'],
       'last_name' => $row['last_name'],
       'next_of_kin' => $given_name
   ]);
}
```